# Share my self evaluation form with direct reports

Tags: leadership

I am thinking of sharing my self evaluation performance review form with my direct reports. This form if going to my manager but I think it would be good to share to my reports in the interests of transparency and openness

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "I am thinking..." Are you sure? because it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: If I were you manager I would not allow that at all. Some things are meant to be private.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea... "here everybody that reports to me, this is what I think of myself"... I don't see an up side to this. If you want transparency, have *them* fill out forms about *you* anonymously.

Comment: The real benefit is not in sharing this, but in listening to the opinions of the direct reports. They have different experiences and making a safe place for them to express their opinions of your actions would greatly enhance the team processes.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to accomplish with sharing your self evaluation (or the evaluation your boss did for you)? What should your subordinates do with that information?

"Hey, look, I think I'm a good boss, because X, Y and Z." So what? Should they agree? Should they disagree? Should they say anything at all? If you want feedback you could ask your reports for it. Maybe even anonymous.

If you really want to publish something just for the sake of it, publish that feedback. But I wouldn't understand the reasoning behind that. If it's stellar, it feels like bragging. If it's mediorce, you weaken yourself by telling all your reports (also the ones who haven't reported anything negative) "Hey, if you haven't noticed already, I'm a bad manager!"